# Is it possible to change a blog's theme through XML-RPC command? (and if so how?)

Tags: xml-rpc

I can't seem to find such an option listed here:

http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_wp#wp.setOptions

Does it exist?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that option does not currently exist through XML-RPC.  However, you can always create your own method in a plugin and hook it up to XML-RPC.

---

### Update

There's an upcoming [Google Summer of Code](http://wordpress.org/gsoc/) project that will be extending the XML-RPC interface to allow direct manipulation of themes, so I won't give away code to implement that here.  But keep your ears and eyes open for when new code (core changes and/or plugins) start releasing this summer.

In the meantime, I will provide an alternative.  The set of options that you can view and set through XML-RPC is filterable.  Basically, you can tell the system to give you more information than it normally would.

What you can already get (bold options are read only ... you can't change them with `wp.setOptions` but you can retrieve them with `wp.getOptions`):

- **software_name**
- **software_version**
- **blog_url**
- **content_width**
- time_zone
- blog_title
- blog_tagline
- date_format
- time_format
- users_can_register
- thumbnail_size_w
- thumbnail_size_h
- thumbnail_crop
- medium_size_w
- medium_size_h
- large_size_w
- large_size_h

This list (actually, an array with other settings), is passed through the `xmlrpc_blog_options` filter, which means you can add and remove to this list all you want.  To enable the fetching of the current theme by `wp.getOptions` and the changing of the theme by `wp.setOptions` you'd use the following:

```
function allow_xmlrpc_theme_changes( $xmlrpcoptions ) {
    $xmlrpcoptions['active-theme'] = array(
        'desc'            => __( 'Active site theme' ),
        'readonly'        => false,
        'option'          => 'template'
    );

    $xmlrpcoptions['active-stylesheet'] = array(
        'desc'            => __( 'Active site stylesheet' ),
        'readonly'        => false,
        'option'          => 'stylesheet'
    );

    return $xmlrpcoptions
}

add_filter( 'xmlrpc_blog_options', 'allow_xmlrpc_theme_changes' );
```

This adds two fields that you can set: "active-theme" and "active-stylesheet".

Remember, you'll be setting these options the same way as you would using `update_option()`, so [double check the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Option_Reference#Themes) before doing anything.

Comment: A small example please

Comment: Plenty of examples available if you search - here are 2: http://josephscott.org/archives/2008/11/adding-xml-rpc-methods-to-wordpress/ and http://www.franzone.com/2009/01/01/a-wordpress-plugin-hello-xml-rpc-world/

Comment: I added an alternative example that uses a filter to expand the list of options available to existing requests.  Creating a theme-specific XML-RPC method is a project currently being pursued by a GSoC student ...

Comment: EAMann Great answer and congrats on being one of the GSCoC mentors.

Answer (score 1):

I've been interested in the same thing.  I put together a plugin that extends XML-RPC to the wp_get_themes function and the switch_theme function.  The plugin is on [Github](https://github.com/dailyinvention/xml-rpc-theme-changer) and I have a walkthrough on [my blog](http://blog.dailyinvention.com/changing-your-wordpress-theme-using-xml-rpc-part-i/).

Comment: Link only answer are discouraged. Answers should be as stand-alone as possible.